# Undeclared identifier database table not recognized

Tags: database, delphi, delphi-2010

```
uses dmInfo;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

begin

with dmInfo do

begin

tblInfo.Open;

end;
```

For some obscure reason, tblInfo is regarded as a undeclared identifier. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Having seen you apparently agree that you named your datamodule something like "DataModule", it's obvious that the real problem is the way you go about naming things.  You seem to have your naming priorities the wrong way around:  First you should give the important **object** a meaningful name, dmInfo instead of DataModule, and then choose the unit's name based upon the object's name, with a systematic suffix (like dmInfou) or prefix.  If you got into that habit you would avoid the sort of slip that gave rise to this q.  Also, avoid "with" like the plague.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiler cannot resolve what 'tblInfo' is because you have not qualifed it. It is not something directly in the scope of unit 'dmInfo' but most probably belong to the data module that's in 'dmInfo'. So, say, if your data module's name is 'DataModule', you'd write

```
with dmInfo.DataModule do

begin

tblInfo.Open;
```

You can omit the unit name if that wouldn't cause any ambiguity.

```
with DataModule do
```

Better yet, start avoiding `with` now and save yourself from possible obscure problems.

```
 DataModule.tblInfo.Open;
```

Comment: Nice catch, +1, but it's pity to miss the opportunity to point out that this is the sort of problem "with" lets people slip into.

Comment: @Martyn - At least this code didn't compile. <g> Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the problem is directly related with 'with' though. Poster could still try to qualify the table as 'dmInfo.tblInfo'.

Comment: Maybe not, but see my comment to the q.